# Usage of sprintf with Format

Tags: c

Given is the following code

```
char str[200];
str[0] = '\0';
double averrage[NUMBER_INPUTS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INPUTS; i++) {
   ...

        sprintf(str, "%s%.3f;", str, averrage[i]);
}
```

I am trying to understand sprintf, but I cant. Specialy because of the variable `str`.

I hope anybody can helps me, to understand.

Comment: Since `str` is recurringly (re-)injected the numbers will be concatenated in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf(str, "%s%.3f;", str, averrage[i]);` is *undefined behavior*.

With `sprintf()`, attempting to read and write to the same pointer `str` makes for bad code.

> ... If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>   C11dr §7.21.6.6 2

---

Sample idea to concatenate follows.

```
char str[200];
str[0] = '\0';
char *p = str;
double averrage[NUMBER_INPUTS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INPUTS; i++) {
   int n = sprintf(p, "%.3f;", averrage[i]);
   if (n < 0) break;
   p += n;
}
puts(str);
```

Additional code is needed to prevent `str` overrun.  Consider `snprintf()`.

Comment: at me it works, but i didn't unterstand it, when i swa this code ;)

Comment: @Doan Code prints the number into `p`.  `n` is the number of characters printed.  So `p += n;` updated `p` to the end of the string.